# PHP Timezone database is corrupt error

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, timezone

I have a wordpress website which suddenly stopped working today. When I look at the logs I see and error:

> [error] [client 50.78.108.177] PHP Fatal error:  strtotime(): Timezone
>   database is corrupt - this should *never* happen!

After reading up on google one person said that they discovered a permissions problem in */usr/share/zoneinfo*. I tried changing the permissions to 777, 775, 770 and I still keep on getting the same error. I am running php PHP 5.3.2 on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS. Any suggestions or recommendations would be helpful.If all else fails I'm going to try downgrading to an earlier version of php but I wanted to try other things before doing that.

thanks,
Timnit

**Update**
just in case it helps: the error points to `strtotime` in the function below

```
function mysql2date( $dateformatstring, $mysqlstring, $translate = true ) {
    $m = $mysqlstring;
    if ( empty( $m ) )
            return false;

    if ( 'G' == $dateformatstring )
            return strtotime( $m . ' +0000' );

    $i = strtotime( $m );

    if ( 'U' == $dateformatstring )
            return $i;

    if ( $translate )
            return date_i18n( $dateformatstring, $i );
    else
            return date( $dateformatstring, $i );
}
```

**Update#2:**
for now I have fixed the problem by simply having the function above `return false;` without performing anything. However I still haven't figured out the root cause of the problem.

**update#3:**

```
var_dump($dateformatstring)
```

> string(5) "d.m.y" string(1) "m" string(5) "d.m.y" string(1) "m"
>   string(5) "d.m.y" string(1)  "m"

```
var_dump($mysqlstring)
```

> string(19) "2011-10-20 05:35:01" string(19) "2011-10-20 05:35:01"
>   string(19) "2011-10-20 05:25:22" string(19) "2011-10-20 05:25:22"
>   string(19) "2011-10-19 05:10:06" string(19) "2011-10-19 05:10:06"

**update#4**:
there is another code snippet that is generating the error log below:

> PHP Fatal error:  date(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should
>   *never* happen! in /srv/www/motionthink.com/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php
>   on **line 346,** referer:
>   wp_root_directory/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=upgrade

```
309         function dirlist($path, $include_hidden = true, $recursive = false) {
  310                 if ( $this->is_file($path) ) {
  311                         $limit_file = basename($path);
  312                         $path = dirname($path);
  313                 } else {
  314                         $limit_file = false;
  315                 }
  316 
  317                 if ( ! $this->is_dir($path) )
  318                         return false;
  319 
  320                 $dir = @dir($path);
  321                 if ( ! $dir )
  322                         return false;
  323 
  324                 $ret = array();
  325 
  326                 while (false !== ($entry = $dir->read()) ) {
  327                         $struc = array();
  328                         $struc['name'] = $entry;
  329 
  330                         if ( '.' == $struc['name'] || '..' == $struc['name'] )
  331                                 continue;
  332 
  333                         if ( ! $include_hidden && '.' == $struc['name'][0] )
  334                                 continue;
  335 
  336                         if ( $limit_file && $struc['name'] != $limit_file)
  337                                 continue;
  338 
  339                         $struc['perms']         = $this->gethchmod($path.'/'.$entry);
  340                         $struc['permsn']  = $this->getnumchmodfromh($struc['perms']);
  341                         $struc['number']        = false;
  342                         $struc['owner']         = $this->owner($path.'/'.$entry);
  343                         $struc['group']         = $this->group($path.'/'.$entry);
  344                         $struc['size']          = $this->size($path.'/'.$entry);
  345                         $struc['lastmodunix']= $this->mtime($path.'/'.$entry);
  346                         $struc['lastmod']   = date('M j',$struc['lastmodunix']);
  347                         $struc['time']          = date('h:i:s',$struc['lastmodunix']);
  348                  $struc['type']          = $this->is_dir($path.'/'.$entry) ?   'd:'f';
  349
```

**Update#5:**
doing a `php -i | fgrep -i date` returns

> Build Date => Dec 13 2011 18:43:02
>
> ```
> date
> date/time support => enabled
> date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
> date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
> date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
> date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
> date.timezone => no value => no value
> ```

then I edited the php.ini file to set the timezone to "America/Los Angeles" and got this output

```
date/time support => enabled
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => America/Los_Angeles => America/Los_Angeles
```

I then restarted apache2. I still get the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was file permissions. I gave the apache2 user read & execute access to usr/share/zoneinfo and etc/localtime. Before, I hadn't set the parents of local time to the right permissions as well. i.e. I only changed the permissions of localtime and zoneinfo without changing the permissions of their parent directories. So stupid! Stepping away from a problem and getting back to it is always useful.

Comment: *sad panda*, all that debugging :/

Answer (score 26):

This issue can also occur when using php-fpm in chroot mode, the solution in this case to be to create something like /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe in your chroot dir then copy your TZ file in to it e.g. London

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed after chrooting my Apache server and only certain PHP scripts were breaking.  Turning on error logging I found this was the issue (although I simply copied everything from `/usr/share/zoneinfo/*` into my chroot jail instead).

Comment: This happened to me after changing the System TimeZone to something else. My chroot containers had only copied "UTC" into the zoneinfo folder. I copied the whole folder from /usr/share/zoneinfo/* to resolve.

Comment: Thanks, I ran into this and crashed PHP as a result. A bind mount might ensure you stay up to date, like the following: `mkdir -p  /var/www/siteroot/usr/share/zoneinfo`, add `/usr/share/zoneinfo     /var/www/siteroot/usr/share/zoneinfo        none    bind,ro,noatime 0       0` to `/etc/fstab`, then `mount /var/www/siteroot/usr/share/zoneinfo`

Answer (score 8):

## Root cause: one of the zoneinfo files could not be opened.

**also caused by**: too many open files.

I had the same problem today on Ubuntu 14.04.01-LTS "Trusty Tahr", and tried the other answers with no benefit. Permissions were OK, the files were there, the content was as expected.

At last I resolved to run the script from within a command line harness, so that I could try with `strace`. And this was the result:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/zoneinfo/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 EMFILE (Too many open files)
open("/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab", O_RDONLY) = -1 EMFILE (Too many open files)
stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2652, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome", O_RDONLY) = -1 EMFILE (Too many open files)
write(1, "\nFatal error: Unknown: Timezone "..., 104) = 104
```

**What is happening**

When PHP "accesses the zoneinfo database" it actually tries to open a directory and some files. If some of these operations fail, the "zoneinfo corrupt" message appears, but it simply means that the PHP process could not open those files:

- they were not there (chroot jail, zoneinfo install error)
- they were not there, *nor should they be*: "Europe/Roem" is not a valid timezone but a typo.
- they were there, but with wrong permissions.
- they were there, but the process isn't authorized (SELinux, AppArmor, ...)
- they were there, but the `fopen` operation is temporarily not working

My case was the last one: the **real** problem was that the script was *opening too many temporary files*, and leaving them open while running. There is a limit on how many files can be opened at the same time, and the zoneinfo file was the proverbial last straw. A quick fix temporarily resolved the problem while I bounced the "too many files" problem to the developer responsible.

Actually I suspect that this *also* points to PHP continuously opening and closing the zoneinfo database instead of *caching* it, but it's an investigation for another day.

**Intermittent error**
The "number of open files" thingy is *per process*, not *per PHP script*. So there are two (at least) scenarios which could lead to a hard-to-diagnose, possibly intermittent/nonreproducible error:

- a slow resource leak by some long-running process, e.g. under Racket.
- a resource hogging by another script or subroutine running in the same process, and possibly *not even related to PHP at all*.

A PHP script that, right or wrong, allocates 800 files could work okay until it meets another subprocess that has allocated 224 files. The limit of 1024 open files per process is reached and *in that case* the process fails with a mysterious error (which only refers, cryptically at that, to the very last symptom in a long chain of concurrent causes).

## Apache: too many web sites.

Apache running with `mod_php5` will cause files accessed by PHP to be opened by the Apache process. But the Apache process also keeps its *log files* open, and every process has a handle to every log file.

So if you have 200 web sites, each with an independent access_log, say `/var/www/somesite/logs/access_log`, each process will start with some 210 handles already taken for housekeeping, leaving some 800 free for PHP to use.

This can lead to a situation where the development server (with one site) works, and the production server (with 200 sites installed) does not, if the script needs to allocate 900 temporary files at once.

**Dirty diagnostics (on Unix/Linux)**: `glob` `/proc/self/fd` and `count()` the result. Ugly as sin, but it gives a ballpark figure on how many file descriptors are actually open.

**Quick and dirty fix (on Unix/Linux)**: increase the fdlimit on per-process open files, bringing it to 1024 (of course you need to be root). It's more a matter for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/20183/apache-crashing-too-many-open-files-in-system).

Comment: Indeed this became the case, when I was coding an uploader with chunk and concurrency support.

Answer (score 2):

You mention 'downgrading', did you recently upgrade? In PHP 5.3.x you are forced to set a valid value for `date.timezone` in your php.ini file.

If you didn't recently upgrade you try resolving the issue by re-installing the `tzdata` package. I work exclusively with CentOS, so I am not sure what the name of Ubuntu's package manager is, but I'm pretty sure `tzdata` is standard across distros.

```
$ -> yum reinstall tzdata # switch 'yum' for Ubuntu package manager
$ -> rm -f /etc/localtime
$ -> ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime # 'UTC' can be replaced with what you prefer
$ -> date # check to see that it stuck
```

You may want to restart your httpd after this to ensure timezone info is picked up.

-- Edit

Looks like the culprit is your date_i18n() function, which is always being called, unless calling code specifically passes a 3rd arg of 'false'. I ran your code through some test data with $translate set to false, and worked fine.

```
function mysql2date( $dateformatstring, $mysqlstring, $translate = true ) {

    $translate = false;
    ...
    if ( $translate )
        return 'date_i18n would have been called';
        //return date_i18n( $dateformatstring, $i );
    ...
}

$testPatterns = array(
    array(
        'dateformatstring'  => 'd.m.y',
        'mysqlstring'       => '2011-10-20 05:35:01'
    ),
    array(
        'dateformatstring'  => 'm',
        'mysqlstring'       => '2011-10-20 05:35:01'
    ),
    array(
        'dateformatstring'  => 'd.m.y',
        'mysqlstring'       => '2011-10-20 05:25:22'
    )
);

foreach ($testPatterns as $testPattern) {

    // Not passing arg to over-ride $translate, forces call to date_i18n()
    var_dump(mysql2date($testPattern['dateformatstring'], $testPattern['mysqlstring']));

    // Forcing $translate to false, makes date() call which works fine
    var_dump(mysql2date($testPattern['dateformatstring'], $testPattern['mysqlstring'], false));
}
```

Comment: <?php
2
        echo date("r");
3
?>

Comment: sorry I meant to say do you think that I should still reinstall tzdata even thought the php script in my comment above returned the date? Also, I recently performed an apt-get update

Comment: I reinstalled tzdata (apt-get install --reinstall tzdata) and it tells me that Local time is now: Thu Jan  5 15:39:24 PST 2012.
Universal Time is now: Thu Jan  5 23:39:24 UTC 2012.

Comment: @TimnitGebru: That looks good. Try restarting your httpd, and see if your issue is resolved.

Comment: thanks. I restarted apache by performing /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Comment: @TimnitGebru: I see you updated your post with code, can you also post a `var_dump($mysqlstring)`, and `var_dump($dateformatstring)`?

Comment: thanks so much for your help Digital Precision. I'm not quite sure how to proceed because this is not my code. This is code that comes as part of wordpress. It is found in wordpress_root_directory/wp-includes/functions.php. I changed the default setting of $translate=false but that didn't solve the problem. I guess the function calling mysql2date is passing $translate=true. I still don't understand why it is suddenly broken.

Comment: @TimnitGebru: Be sure your running the latest version of the software. You may want to check with you hosting provider that they didn't recently make any changes. Also do some search on Wordpress forums for anyone that may be having similar issues.

Comment: @TimnitGebru: You can set `$translate = false` at the start of the function and override any incoming values, so you are forcing it through php's `date()` and not the custom function. Updated post to reflect change.

Comment: Hi Digital Precision, I just upgraded to wordpress 3.3.1 and the same problem persists. Also, when I try to update plugins, I get the following error log:

Comment: Thanks again for continuing to help me. I run an unmanaged linode server. I upgraded to wordpress 3.3.1 and the same problem persists. For now I have mysql2date just return false and that seems to work but  now I can't upgrade the wordpress plugins because I get another date() related error. I have updated my post with an error log and the related code.

Comment: @TimnitGebru: I use linode too, good stuff. I wouldn't just return false from mysql2date, I would set translate to false, it may be enough to get your plugin working. Can you do me a favor and do a `php -i | fgrep -i date` from your shell, and paste the contents in your OP?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that I set $translate=false and it was still not working. The error is on mysql2date is on line 33 where it says  $i = strtotime( $m );I have just updated my OP with the php -i | fgrep -i date output.

Comment: What do you get when you do a `date` via shell?

Comment: Oops sorry I keep on entering my comments before I'm done. Per Fatih Abdullah's suggestion below I ran the command echo date("r") in php earlier and got Thu, 05 Jan 2012 15:20:54

Comment: Run it from the shell... I'm curious to see which timezone is set.

Comment: I wrote a script called time.php: #!/usr/bin/php
<?php
  echo date("r");
?>   and did chmod +x time.php and ran ./time.php. Is that what you mean? Then the output I get is Thu, 05 Jan 2012 22:32:15 -0800

Comment: Php has you in LA timezone, hence the -0800. Type `date` in your terminal.

Comment: date in terminal shows Thu Jan  5 22:52:13 PST 2012. I just did a var_dump of struc['lastmodunix'] from line 345-6 of the second snippet of code I posted and stored it in a variable $variable. Executing date('M j',$variable)from the shell then gives me no error and I get the output: Jan 5. Maybe the date() function wordpress is using is somewhere else? I'm really confused

Comment: Try rebooting the server. I know, cliche, but I had a time zone prob with my linode boxes too. Maybe a reset after your yz data reinstall will work.

Comment: @TimnitGebru: Did you figure it out?

Comment: no :) I'm back at at it tomorrow. I'll update if I figure it out

Comment: This helped. Downloaded a Docker container with WordPress from appcontainers.com and had to perform this in order to install and run WP there correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I change localtime file for my GMT setting like
mv /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Karachi localtime
Then followinf error occurs.

date_default_timezone_get(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen!

Solution : Revert you local time setting.
Tips : Always keep a backup copy of your old local time so that you can recover any expected OS / Software issue

Answer (score -2):

may be this can help you [PHP – Set Timezone](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/01/26/php-set-timezone/)

Comment: thanks for that. When I follow the instructions it does show the date: Thu, 05 Jan 2012 15:20:54