# Fatal error: date(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen

Tags: php, database, date, timezone

I'm throwing a "Fatal error: date(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen!" error. It says the error is one the first line of this code:

```
$day = date("D");
$hour =  date("j");
$weekday = true;
$weekend = true;
$open = true;
```

I'm *very* new to PHP and I can't seem to get past this hurdle.

Please help! :)

Comment: Well, for errors that should *never* happen one's better check (and show in the question) the installation details: file privileges, server configuration etc.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48882 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751221/php-timezone-database-is-corrupt-error

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be fixed by removing the sym link at /etc/localtime
Bonus tip: Instead of removing it, just rename it.