# PHP command line error : Timezone database is corrupt

Tags: php, date, permissions, timezone

My date.php is -

```
<?php
echo date('Y');
```

When I execute `php -f date.php` on my staging machine, I get error -

```
PHP Fatal error:  date(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! 
in /home/staging/test/date.php on line 2
```

But when I execute the same on my local / dev machine it works. Although on both staging and local machines, permissions on `/etc/localtime` and `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` are the same.

But output of `file /etc/localtime` vary on both machines.

**Local (php5.3.5)** :

```
/etc/localtime: timezone data, version 2, 4 gmt time flags, 4 std time flags, no leap seconds, 4 transition times, 4 abbreviation chars
```

**Staging (php5.3.10)** :

```
/etc/localtime: timezone data, version 2, 1 gmt time flag, 1 std time flag, no leap seconds, no transition times, 1 abbreviation char
```

While trying to find what the issue is I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751221/php-timezone-database-is-corrupt-error) from SO. I am confused over the accepted answer. **My apache user is not executing the script**.

What seems to be the problem? How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: take a look at this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48882

Comment: Update my question with 1 more finding. Please see.

Comment: Can this be the issue? - http://ivanbayan.com/index.php/2013/06/26/how-to-fix-timezone-database-is-corrupt-this-should-never-happen/ But why the issues from php5-fmp causing problems in core php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Timezone database is corrupt error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751221/php-timezone-database-is-corrupt-error)

Answer (score 1):

For various reasons, PHP ships with its own timezone database - it is possible to use the system TZDB by configuring the software differently at compile time.

The PHP timezonedb is implemented as [C code](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) (lots of defines) - hence you need to recompile PHP to get it working.

If your PHP interpreter is not explicitly configured to use the OS timezoneDB, then you really need to investigate why the executable is corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check permission of your timezone files.It might have changed when you have  install some rpms. 
change the permission to 655
Also check following files:

/usr
/lib
/share
/etc
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was running php-fpm in chroot mode.  I changed it to run without a chroot, and then the error went away.