# mysqli_real_connect(): Invalid date.timezone value. Timezone database is corrupt

Tags: mysql

[PHP Timezone database is corrupt error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751221/php-timezone-database-is-corrupt-error/54425235#54425235)

But for the life of me i can't seem to fix the problem, this is my current error:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): Invalid date.timezone value 'Europe/London', we selected the timezone 'UTC' for now. in `/var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php` on line 1531
>
> Fatal error: mysqli_real_connect(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! `in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php` on line 1531

This is the Line 1531:

```php
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
                mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
            } else {
                @mysqli_real_connect( $this->dbh, $host, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpassword, null, $port, $socket, $client_flags );
```

I have added to the php.ini file the date.timezone = 'Europe/London'

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = 'Europe/London'
```

Comment: "can't seem to fix the problem" → be more detailed which fixes you attempted. Your question/repost doesn't give away the curernt php.ini settings, nor process or filesystem permissions.

Comment: Are you running into this error on localhost?

Comment: I'm using a Linode server

Comment: I've given permissions to the php.ini file

Comment: Have you tried running your installation on localhost?

Comment: I am unable to do that unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a permissions issue caused due to the restrictions imposed by your current web host. Contact your host to help you with this issue. You can also see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8799997/3565182

You can verify it by running your wordpress installation on your local machine with XAMPP.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, i just restored the website to an older version, that's the only way i could fix this problem, again many thanks

Comment: You may want to upvote my answer, if it was of any use to you.