# PHP working but Laravel not, returns 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php, laravel, apache, http-status-code-503

The error_log is:

```
[Thu Feb 21 13:07:41.791781 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 19304] [client 59.547.36.85:57554] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Notice:  date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'Asia/Tehran' is invalid in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php on line 49
PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /public/index.php:0
PHP message: PHP   2. App\\Http\\Kernel->handle() /public/index.php:54
PHP message: PHP   3. App\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:116
PHP message: PHP   4. App\\Http\\Kernel->bootstrap() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:146
PHP message: PHP   5. Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:162
PHP message: PHP   6. Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:211
PHP message: PHP   7. date_default_timezone_set() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php:49
PHP message: PHP Warning:  Uncaught ErrorException: DateTime::createFromFormat(): Invalid date.timezone value 'Asia/Tehran', we selected the timezone 'UTC' for now. in /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ResponseHeaderBag.php:295
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'DateTime::creat...', '/vendor/symfony...', 295, Array)
#1 /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ResponseHeaderBag.php(295): DateTime::createFromFormat('U', '1550741861')
#2 /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ResponseHeaderBag.php(41): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ResponseHeaderBag->initDate()
#3 /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(201): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ResponseHeaderBag->__construct(Array)
#4 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(750): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#5 /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(722): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse(Object(Illuminat...
PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /public/index.php:0
PHP message: PHP   2. App\\Http\\Kernel->handle() /public/index.php:54
PHP message: PHP   3. App\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:116
PHP message: PHP   4. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->then() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:151
PHP message: PHP   5. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:104
PHP message: PHP   6. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP   7. App\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP   8. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:62
PHP message: PHP   9. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  10. Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  11. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27
PHP message: PHP  12. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  13. App\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  14. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:31
PHP message: PHP  15. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  16. Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  17. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:31
PHP message: PHP  18. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  19. App\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  20. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php:57
PHP message: PHP  21. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  22. Barryvdh\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  23. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/barryvdh/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php:36
PHP message: PHP  24. App\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
PHP message: PHP  25. Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:176
PHP message: PHP  26. Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:614
PHP message: PHP  27. Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:625
PHP message: PHP  28. Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:659
PHP message: PHP  29. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->then() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:684
PHP message: PHP  30. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:104
PHP message: PHP  31. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  32. App\\Http\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  33. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:66
PHP message: PHP  34. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  35. Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  36. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37
PHP message: PHP  37. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  38. Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  39. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php:63
PHP message: PHP  40. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  41. Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsF

    [Thu Feb 21 13:07:41.791912 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 19304] [client 59.547.36.85:57554] AH01071: Got error 'closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  44. App\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  45. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php:75
PHP message: PHP  46. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  47. Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  48. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php:41
PHP message: PHP  49. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  50. Barryvdh\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  51. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/barryvdh/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php:36
PHP message: PHP  52. Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
PHP message: PHP  53. Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:682
PHP message: PHP  54. Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:722
PHP message: PHP  55. Illuminate\\Http\\Response->__construct() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:750
PHP message: PHP  56. Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ResponseHeaderBag->__construct() /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:201
PHP message: PHP  57. Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ResponseHeaderBag->initDate() /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ResponseHeaderBag.php:41
PHP message: PHP  58. DateTime::createFromFormat() /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ResponseHeaderBag.php:295
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  DateTime::createFromFormat(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen! in /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ResponseHeaderBag.php on line 295
PHP message: PHP Stack trace:
PHP message: PHP   1. {main}() /public/index.php:0
PHP message: PHP   2. App\\Http\\Kernel->handle() /public/index.php:54
PHP message: PHP   3. App\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:116
PHP message: PHP   4. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->then() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:151
PHP message: PHP   5. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:104
PHP message: PHP   6. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP   7. App\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP   8. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:62
PHP message: PHP   9. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  10. Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  11. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php:27
PHP message: PHP  12. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  13. App\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  14. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:31
PHP message: PHP  15. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  16. Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  17. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php:31
PHP message: PHP  18. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  19. App\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  20. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php:57
PHP message: PHP  21. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  22. Barryvdh\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  23. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/barryvdh/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php:36
PHP message: PHP  24. App\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:30
PHP message: PHP  25. Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:176
PHP message: PHP  26. Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:614
PHP message: PHP  27. Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:625
PHP message: PHP  28. Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:659
PHP message: PHP  29. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->then() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:684
PHP message: PHP  30. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:104
PHP message: PHP  31. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  32. App\\Http\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  33. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php:66
PHP message: PHP  34. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  35. Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  36. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php:37
PHP message: PHP  37. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:53
PHP message: PHP  38. Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:163
PHP message: PHP  39. Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing

[Thu Feb 21 13:07:41.819083 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 19304] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 59.547.36.85:57554] AH01075: Error dispatching request to :
```

but when I `die('Working!')` in `public/index.php` it returns `Working!`. However when I remove that `die` Laravel returns that error!

I'm using

`PHP 7.2.14`
`Laravel Framework 5.7.27`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Something in Laravel error logs?

Comment: No, it's entirely blank!

Comment: php and laravel version?

Comment: Updated the question. thanks

Comment: The stack trace seems to be triggered by `PHP Notice:  date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'Asia/Tehran' is invalid`. Have you tried to fix that?

Comment: try to change the timezone, for example `'timezone' => 'UTC',` in `config/app.php`

Comment: Yeah I had done that, but again error exists! I changed it in php.ini too. but no result! BTW that's only a notice but the next line there is an error!

Comment: Is that a fresh install of Laravel? Is it possible that some files are "corrupted"?

Comment: if you are not in production try to regenerate the key: `php artisan key:generate`
Have you recently upgraded Laravel?

Comment: @dparoli I did it no result :(

Comment: @HamzStramGram yeah I guess they are corrupted, could you tell me how I can reinstall it again? I guess I should delete vendor and run composer install, shouldn't I?

Comment: @kodfire Yes, that's something you could try.

Comment: Scrolled half way across the second line and found this: `PHP Fatal error:  DateTime::createFromFormat(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen!`. It might be worth enabling Laravel's `debug` mode in your `.env` (by adding `DEBUG=true` to make it easier to spot the errors instead of getting a blank page. It's difficult to see them when everything's on one line

Comment: Well, this is definitely unclear but you can this github's issue : https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8102

Comment: @HamzStramGram I have already tried that same error! doesn't it related to Files and Folders permissions? or maybe `php-fpm` fcgi?

Comment: Following with @DaveS 's answer, this can maybe help with the `PHP Fatal error` : http://ivanbayan.com/index.php/2013/06/26/how-to-fix-timezone-database-is-corrupt-this-should-never-happen/

Comment: @DaveS I had enabled that, the problem is that it doesn't get until that point, before running laravel it throws error. but only returns string when I die in `public/index.php`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751221/php-timezone-database-is-corrupt-error

Comment: FINALLY :)) Thanks @DaveS and all other helped me :)

Comment: it seems your timezone not valid. So try to set valid timezone in config.php file.

Comment: I meant @DaveS link was helpful by "FINALLY" and now it's working :)

Comment: @kodfire Glad you got it working, I'll summarise my comments in a proper answer. With that, you'll be able to mark it as resolved so that people know it's no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the key to finding your issue is in the following notice:

```
date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'Asia/Tehran' is invalid
```

This is related to the fatal error further down the logs:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen!.
```

Emphasis on **Timezone database is corrupt**. The reason Laravel fails completely is because it's trying to create timestamps to go with the response (possibly for the stack trace of the initial `date_default_timezone_set` notice). That in turn results in the fatal error. You can see this in the stack trace directly above the fatal error:

```
PHP message: PHP  55. Illuminate\\Http\\Response->__construct() /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:750
PHP message: PHP  56. Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ResponseHeaderBag->__construct() /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:201
PHP message: PHP  57. Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ResponseHeaderBag->initDate() /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ResponseHeaderBag.php:41
PHP message: PHP  58. DateTime::createFromFormat() /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ResponseHeaderBag.php:295
```

To fix your issue you should figure out exactly *why* PHP can't work with the timezone database. There could be a couple causes, but for more information you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751221/php-timezone-database-is-corrupt-error) which contains a few answers.