# Laravel Timezone database is corrupt

Tags: php, linux, laravel, amazon-ec2, centos

I am getting below error and it stops the application. Manually needs to restart server.

```
[error] FastCGI sent in stderr:
 "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: date_default_timezone_get():
 Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never happen! in
 /path/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php on line 461
PHP message: PHP Fatal error: date_default_timezone_get(): Timezone database is corrupt -
 this should never happen! in /path/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php 
on line 317" while reading response header from upstream,
this was the error log on ec2 instance during issue
```

I don't understand the root cause of this error and why it down the application. Does anyone know any fixes?

Till now I have tried to increase the rlimit_files value in PHP-fpm.conf but that doesn't help to fix.

Any solution in this?

Comment: have u updated your all packages ?

Comment: @KamleshPaul laravel packages?

Comment: it seems problem with carbon so yes laravel packages which include carbon

Comment: I dont think it's a carbon issue...

Comment: `Carbon.php on line 461` check this

Comment: What about Logger line 317? In any case, `date_default_timezone_get` is producing it. I myself am not sure, It's either PHP issue or, as is often the case with these types of errors, a permission issue. Did you change any configurations before this happened?

Comment: Oh, looks like loads of SO with same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103186/timezone-database-is-corrupt references a php bug. This one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751221/php-timezone-database-is-corrupt-error highlights a permission issue. I think these would help you.

Comment: @user3532758 Yes, I have referred all those but no solution worked

Comment: @BhumiShah https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73015 can u try this .?

Comment: @KamleshPaul They have not accepted any answer or nor assurance that zoneinfo changes works perfectly

Comment: @BhumiShah then update php version  and all package update all will work